# Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: r

I tried to split the data(bank) into training data and test data. But I somehow got an error below.How can I solve this problem?

```
train = bank[1:100, ]
test = bank[!train,]
Status.test =Status[!train]
glm.fit=glm(Status~Length+Right+Bottom+Top+Diagonal,data=bank,family=binomial,subset=train)

#Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'

glm.probs=predict(glm.fit,test,type="response") 
glm.pred=rep("genuine",100)  
glm.pred[glm.probs>.5]="counterfeit"
table(glm.pred,test)##classification on training data

#Error in table(glm.pred, test) : all arguments must have the same length
```

Comment: Maybe use `-(1:100)` instead of `!train` -- it's not clear what you're trying to do there.  You may also be interested in the `split` function.

Comment: It gets me the same error. bank data contains 200 rows so I want to split two parts and test my model into the test subset.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is in `subset=train`. According to the `?glm`. the `subset` should be a vector as oppose to a subset of original dataset:

> subset     an optional vector specifying a subset of observations to be
>   used in the fitting process.

Hence, you may need to change the code to:
`glm.fit=glm(Status~Length+Right+Bottom+Top+Diagonal,data=train,family=binomial)`

or

`glm.fit=glm(Status~Length+Right+Bottom+Top+Diagonal,data=bank,family=binomial,subset=1:100)`

Comment: I solve this first one. But I tried the second one, it generates  an error.  >table(glm.pred,Status.test)##classification on training data
Error in table(glm.pred, Status.test) : 
  all arguments must have the same length      
> length(Status.test);length(glm.pred)
[1] 68
[1] 60

Comment: @K.heer, To compare the prediction with actual, you can use `table(glm.pred,test$Status)`, assuming there is a `Status` column in `bank` dataset as response variable.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you could achieve what you asked by doing something like this:
Assume column 'response' is observed column:

```
samples=1:100
train = bank[samples, ]
test = bank[-samples,]
Status.test =bank[samples,'response']
```

BTW, I would suggest using `sample()` function in order to take samples randomly for train and test. like this:

```
samples=sample(nrow(bank), 0.8*nrow(bank))
train = bank[samples, ]
test = bank[-samples,]
Status.test =bank[samples,'response']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the training data like:

```
data[1: 100,]
```

Then in `lm()` function you use the argument:

```
data = bank[train,]
```

Alternatively you can set train like:

```
seq(1: 100)
```

as a sequence of indices, you need to use in the

```
lm(): data = bank, subset = train
```